# Sumif with 2 Options

Tags: excel, sumifs

I do have have an Excel sheet - looks like this:

```
-----------------------------
|Sites  |Domains  |   Visits|
-----------------------------
|anysite|facebook |       10|
-----------------------------
|somsite|facebook |        5|
-----------------------------
|anysite|twitter  |        5|
-----------------------------
```

Id like to have a function which counts the Visits if in column A is anysite and in  B facebook.

Because there are many variations of facebook id like to work with joker:

```
=SumIfs(C:C;A:A;"anysite";B:B;"*facebook*")
```

The result should be 10

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: But I need the joker!

Comment: I am unable to understand your question. Can you properly state that?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's [working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNo9S.png) for me?

Comment: What he means is that he is expecting multiple variations of the word `facebook` and therefore needs to employ some sort of wildcard like asterisk (*), (which he is calling joker).

Comment: Then I think @JvdV got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have multiple options (if I understand correctly):

Sample data:

[image]

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C2:C6,A2:A6,"anysite",B2:B6,{"facebook";"FB";"Fbook"}))
```

Or create a range with all the forms facebook can appear in and reference this range, for example:

```
{=SUM(SUMIFS(C2:C6,A2:A6,"anysite",B2:B6,F2:F4))}
```

In which case you'll have to enter it through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You could even decide to create a namedrange or a table with all possible domainsforms facebook could appear in and reference this in the formula.

```
{=SUM(SUMIFS(C2:C6,A2:A6,"anysite",B2:B6,DomainsNamedRange))}
```

Or:

```
{=SUM(SUMIFS(C2:C6,A2:A6,"anysite",B2:B6,DomainsTable))}
```

Comment: Yes, this second thing should work for him. Good in the sense that he can grow it dynamically if he needs to support more variables of FB.

Comment: Thanks @dotNET, that gave me the idea to use a table/namedrange!